# Convergence of $\int_1^2 \frac 1{\sqrt{x^4 - 1}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

I want to show that $\int_1^2 \frac 1{\sqrt{x^4 - 1}}dx$ is convergent.

I tried to use the limit convergence test by comparing with $\frac{1}{x^2}$ but that doesn't work. Any hints on how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fact that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4-1}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$ for all $x>1$. This is because $x^4-1>x-1$ for all $x>1$.

Therefore, we have $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4-1}} < \int_1^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}} = 2\sqrt{x-1} |_1^2 = 2$

Answer (score 3):

You can set $x^2=sect$ and perform this substitution. When you do that, you in up with an integral of the form$\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{cost}}$. The key is in the upper and lower bound. For both $x=1$ and $x=2$ you can conclude that on the corresponding $t$ interval, the function is continuous. in other words, it is no longer an improper integral, the integral has an answer (though through elementary techniques we can' figure that out) thus convergent.

Comment: Simple but does the job (+1). Nice.

Comment: The exact answer is $\frac1{\sqrt2}F(\pi/3,m=1/2)$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel That's not a nice answer....well actually it is a nice answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at the endpoint $1$.
You want to compare with $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\; dx$.
Possibly helpful is
$$  x^4-1 = (x-1)(x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Check that the integral $$I=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{dx}{(x-a)^p}$$ is finte if $p<1$. So
$$J=\int_{1}^{2} \frac{dx}{(x-1)^{1/2} (x+1)^{1/2} \sqrt{x^2+1}},$$
converges as $p=1/2<1$

Answer (score 0):

The only problem *could* be at the lower bound.

But, by Taylor
$$ \frac 1{\sqrt{x^4 - 1}}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x-1}}-\frac{3 \sqrt{x-1}}{8}+O\left((x-1)^{3/2}\right)$$ Then, no problem, and you will get a number (the answer is quite complicated).

But, if you continue the expansion
$$ \frac 1{\sqrt{x^4 - 1}}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x-1}}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n a_n  (x-1)^{n+\frac 12}$$ the first coeffiicients form the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{3}{8},\frac{11}{64},\frac{7}{256},\frac{141}{4096},\frac{627}{16
   384},\frac{2465}{131072},\frac{81}{524288},\frac{142019}{16777216},\cdots\right\}$$ You will have
$$\int_1^t \frac 1{\sqrt{x^4 - 1}}=\sqrt{t-1}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{ a_n }{2 n+3}(t-1)^{n+\frac{3}{2}}$$

Using the above coefficients and $t=2$, the approximation will give
$$\frac{22479314089}{27808235520}\approx 0.8084$$ while the excat value is $0.8078$